# Get the names of a dynamic product group with a subscriber in Shopware 6.1

Tags: shopware

how can I get the names of the dynamic product groups of a product?
Especially the names of that groups. The names are in the table 'product_stream_translation'.
I have a subscriber and have added this Criteria. When I am doing it like this:

```
$criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('id', $id));
$criteria->addAssociation('streams');
$dynamicProductGroups = $this->productRepository->search($criteria, $context)->getEntities();
```

I just got back an empty streamEntity.

```
#streams: Shopware\Core\Content\ProductStream\ProductStreamCollection {#11805 ▼
    #elements: []
    #extensions: []
  }
```

When I am doing it like this:

```
$criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('productId', $id));
$dynamicProductGroups = $this->productStreamMappingRepository->searchIds($criteria, $context);
```

I just got back the Id I put in:
[product_stream_mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3b1v.png)

I wonder how I will get the name of the dynamic product group.
With a query I can get all the assign 'product_stream_id's from the table 'product_stream_mapping' like this:

```
SELECT * FROM product_stream_mapping WHERE product_id =0x000000000000000000123b313030524b
```

And then get the associated name of the dynamic product group. With is like this:

```
SELECT psm.product_id, psm.product_stream_id, p.product_number, pst.name 
FROM product_stream_mapping psm 
JOIN product_stream_translation pst ON pst.product_stream_id = psm.product_stream_id
JOIN product p ON p.id = psm.product_id
WHERE psm.product_id = 0x000000000000000000123b313030524b
```

How can I get it in the Subscriber?
Do I have to use criteria or do I have to user a repository?

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong:

```php
$dynamicProductGroups = $this->productRepository->search($criteria, $context)->getEntities();
```

It won't return dynamic product groups but a product collection. To get a product stream collection (dynamic product groups) replace it with:

```php
/** @var ProductEntity $product */
$product = $this->productRepository->search($criteria, $context)->first();
$dynamicProductGroups = $product->getStreams();
```

Then you can read the names of the streams with:

```php
$names = array_values(
    $dynamicProductGroups->map(fn (ProductStreamEntity $productStream) => $productStream->getName())
);
```

Comment: Great. Thank you for your answer. I have adjusted that.
But I got an error: 
`No product with (000000000000000000534b313030524b) found`

I wonder there is no `$criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('id', $id));`
I have added it but still the error is there.

In your second code example should `$streams->map` be `dynamicProductGroups->map`?

Comment: @Gunnarius sorry, you are right, it should be `$dynamicProductGroups->map`. Your product ID looks like an invalid UUID. You can filter products by ID using `EqualsFilter('id', $id)` just like you did or you can set the product ID in criteria constructor `$criteria = new Criteria([$id]);`.

Comment: Thank you for your answerI could fix it. What is missing is the association to 'streams'. So I have added:
`$criteria->addAssociation('streams');`

Finally it looks like this:
`$criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('id', $id));
 $criteria->addAssociation('streams');`

Your hint with `$product->getStreams();` saved my day. Thank you.

Comment: With this 
`$names = array_values($dynamicProductGroups->map(fn (ProductStreamEntity $productStream) => $productStream->getName())         );`
I got an error: 

`Argument 1 passed to My\Theme\Storefront\Subscriber\ProductDetailSubscriber::My\Theme\Storefront\Subscriber\{closure}() must be an instance of My\Theme\Storefront\Subscriber\ProductStreamEntity, instance of Shopware\Core\Content\ProductStream\ProductStreamEntity given`

Comment: @Gunnarius glad to hear that. You probably have an error in your imports. It should be `use Shopware\Core\Content\ProductStream\ProductStreamEntity;`.

Comment: @Pavel I want from the 'apiFilter' the value of the field "product.tags.id". 

"queries" => array:1 [▼
                0 => array:3 [▼
                  "type" => "equals"
                  "field" => "product.tags.id"
                  "value" => "2ae2440fb6804225977b270a6a61b5fa"
                ]

For that I need a filter, I guess. How can I apply a filter here. Has that to be after adding the association?

Comment: I have seen it. There is `$productStream->getApiFilter()`.